# multer, react-native image upload not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, multer

I am trying to upload a picture with an image picker. I made an image component and make an image-picker fill the component, but uploading the image data to the server doesn't work.

this is the code that is called by onPress attached to a button:

```
const handlePhoto = async () =>{
        if(image!== null){
            console.log(image)
            const fileToUpload = image;
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('name', 'Image Upload');
            data.append('file', fileToUpload);
            let res = await fetch(
                'http://localhost:3000/user/pic_upload',
                {
                method: 'post',
                body: data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; ',
                },
            }
            );  
            let responseJson = await res.json();
            console.log(responseJson,'result')
            if (responseJson.status == 1) {
                alert('Upload Successful');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Please Select File first');
        }
    }
```

and at index file for user router:

```
const upload=multer({
    storage:multer.diskStorage({
        destination:function(req,file,callback){
            callback(null,'uploads/')
        },
        filename:function(req,file,callback){
            callback(null,new Date().valueOf()+path.extname(file.originalname))
        }
    }),
});

router.post('/pic_upload', upload.single('file'), controller.picUpload)
```

and picUpload router just has console.log

What should I fix to make it work?

Comment: Change that `uploads/` to `path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename || process.mainModule.filename), 'public', 'assets', 'uploads')`, if your folder is located in `/public/assets/uploads`

Comment: console `req.file` in your controller and send the results here

Comment: it was undefined before and it still shows undefined

Comment: Check your image in the frontend, is it have the File type like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: I don't know what you mean.. the extension of the image is jpg though

Comment: When you upload the image, you will get a File Type Image, just like this image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Z96.png

Comment: hmm no I don't get anything like that, when I put res in console log it only shows the file location

Comment: LoL, you don't need to pass file location, you need to pass File Type Object in backend

Comment: I just noticed that the console log was for another value, I checked 'data' and it still contains its path, maybe my handlePhoto is just wrong?

Comment: yes, its wrong, please ask frontend developers to send file type object